# Python and CPLEX

Tags: python, cplex

I'm trying to use this command:`python setup.py install`
It doesn't work, It writes: `'cplex' directory doesn't exist`. What should I do to remove that problem?
Also I tried to open `setup.py` (Python version 2.7), but I have an error:

```
no commands supplied.
```

`C:\Users\user>python D:\cplex1\cplex\python\2.7\x64_win64\setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
error: package directory 'cplex' does not exist`

**Edit: The problem has been solved**

Comment: Can you flesh this out with a bit more context please?

Comment: @Ajean
`C:\Users\user>python D:\cplex1\cplex\python\2.7\x64_win64\setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
error: package directory 'cplex' does not exist`

Comment: I 've just added the error message from cmd. I am sorry, I am a bigenner. And I just want to know what the problem is

Comment: (No experience with CPLEX): Try to ```cd``` first to the base-directory where setup.py is existing. E.g. ```cd D:\cplex1\cplex\python\2.7\x64_win64\``` (with win's cmd this might actually more than 1 command as you are switching drives), then call setup.py from this path as base-path like ```C:\Users\user>python.exe setup.py install```.

Comment: @sascha , I've done it, but my PC doesn't let me do that commend. It says: access denied

Comment: Well it's hard to help then. Some basic understanding of the system is needed to install software from the command-line. And your error-description is again way too broad. How do you expect help?

Comment: problem has been solved, thank you @sascha I just downloaded another version of python and did your instructions